# parsing table in XPATH

Tags: java, xpath, nsxmlparser

```
<TR>
 <TD>Field 1</TD>
 <TD colSpan=2>Field 2</TD>
 <TD>Field 3</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
 <TD>Value for Field1</TD>
 <TD colSpan=2>Value for Field2</TD>
 <TD>Value for Field3</TD>
<TR></TR>
</TR>
```

How can i map the Field with its value? I am using XPATH to parse my html file.

And the main problem is the number of fields change in each and every input..But as you know the layout will be same....

Comment: Can you post your XPath string so we have a better idea where you got stuck?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and easy XPath expression that selects the correct node even in the case when the two rows have different number of `TD`s. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/*[2]/TD
         [position()
         =
         count(/*/*[1]
                    /TD[.=$pName]/preceding-sibling::TD
              ) +1
         ]
```

selects the `TD` with "value" corresponding to the "name" specified in the variable `pName`

Thus, if you substitute `$pName` in the above expression with `'Field 2'`,the following will be selected:

```
<TD colSpan="2">Value for Field2</TD>
```

**Note**: This XPath expression selects the correct node even in the case when the two rows have different number of `TD`s.

**To select only the text child node of the `TD`,** append `/text()` to the expression.

**To get just the string value, use**:

```
  string(/*/*[2]/TD
             [position()
             =
             count(/*/*[1]
                        /TD[.=$pName]/preceding-sibling::TD
                  ) +1
             ]
        )
```

**Here is a short XSLT transformation proving that the wanted value is retrieved**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pName" select="'Field 2'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "/*/*[2]/TD
             [position()
             =
             count(/*/*[1]
                        /TD[.=$pName]/preceding-sibling::TD
                  ) +1
             ]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied against the provided XML document** (fixed to be made well-formed):

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>Field 1</TD>
        <TD colSpan="2">Field 2</TD>
        <TD>Field 3</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Value for Field1</TD>
        <TD colSpan="2">Value for Field2</TD>
        <TD>Value for Field3</TD>
        <TR></TR></TR>
</TABLE>
```

**the wanted result is produced:**

```
Value for Field2
```

Answer (score 2):

This will select you field names:

```
//table/tr[position() mod 2 = 0]/td/text()
```

This will select you field values:

```
//table/tr[position() mod 2 = 1]/td/text()
```

Comment: Sorry, but you have an error. When you really try to apply these expressions on the provided XML document, you will see that no node is selected. Please, correct.

Answer (score 1):

With this input:

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>Field 1</TD>
        <TD colSpan="2">Field 2</TD>
        <TD>Field 3</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Value for Field1</TD>
        <TD colSpan="2">Value for Field2</TD>
        <TD>Value for Field3</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

This XPath expression:

```
/TABLE/TR/TD[.='Field 3']/following::TD[count(../TD)]
```

It selects this element:

```
<TD>Value for Field3</TD>
```

**Note**: This assumes a "regular" table.